# How do I center text horizontally within an FPDF generated PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI/FPDF to dynamically add text to a PDF file. I would like for the text to be centered horizontally on the PDF regardless of how long the text is, but I am not sure how to set this using `$pdf->SetXY`

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('test2.pdf');

$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplIdx);

$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, $size['width'], $size['height'],FALSE);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
// Here's what I have tried
$pdf->SetXY($size['width']/2, 100);
//
$pdf->Write(0, 'Lorem Ipsum');

$pdf->Output();
```

I tried to use the width of the imported PDF divided by 2 as the X position, however this makes it so that the text starts at that point rather than being centered on it.

Comment: You could use string width to center it http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/getstringwidth.htm

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!